# Make per-context JNDI variable available to Tomcat in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, tomcat, jndi

I'm using Tomcat 8.5.6 inside Eclipse 4.6.1. I have my web-app project/context `foo`, which has a JAX-RS (using RESTEasy 3.1.0.CR3) endpoint of `bar`, so I can fire up Tomcat inside Eclipse and access:

```
http://localhost:8080/foo/bar
```

I have a variable named `foobar` which I want to access inside my JAX-RS implementation using JNDI:

```
final String foobar = (String) new InitialContext().lookup("java:comp/env/foobar");
```

I plan on deploying the produced WAR in production using Tomcat autodeploy. I want to configure the `foobar` variable for Tomcat externally to the WAR. How can I do that so that I can test it in Eclipse?

After a lot of reading, I found what I thought to be the `$CATALINA_HOME` of Eclipse: `…\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\`. So I created a context file for `foo` at `…\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\conf\Catalina\localhost\foo.xml` to correspond to my project/context, and put the following inside it:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Context>
    <Environment name="foobar" type="java.lang.String" value="123"/>
</Context>
```

Yes, I know that Eclipse erases this directory whenever I rebuild. But after building, I saved to file at least want to see if it works. It doesn't. I get an error:

```
javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Name [foobar] is not bound in this Context. Unable to find [foobar].
```

I want to at least get it working so I can know how to do this in production, and worry later about the context file deletion thing in Eclipse. So what did I do wrong? Why can't Tomcat in Eclipse find this JNDI variable?

Note: I am not using a `web.xml` file and have no desire to do so; besides, this variable should be defined *outside* the WAR in the production deployment.

Update: The good news is that (on Windows 10 Professional Anniversary Edition 64-bit) using the same Tomcat but in standalone mode, I put the same `foobar.xml` file inside the standalone Tomcat's `conf\Catalina\localhost\foo.xml`, and my JAX-RS application picked it up just fine. So how can I define a JNDI variable in Tomcat inside Eclipse for testing?

Answer (score 3):

It appears that in order to get Eclipse+Tomcat to recognize the per-module context files, you have to go into the server configuration (double-click on the server) and turn on the **Publish module contexts to separate XML files**. This way Tomcat will use the specific context XML file you created. Otherwise it apparently puts them in `conf/server.xml` and ignores the context-specific file you created.

There is still the problem that Eclipse regenerates this file each time you do a rebuild, destroying whatever JNDI variables you placed there. I'm trying to get the workaround in https://stackoverflow.com/a/22380248/421049 to work, but not yet succeeding. Anyone have any better ideas?

At least I'm able to reproduce a production environment now --- albeit temporarily, until the next rebuild.

Answer (score 0):

Your link to Markus' answer on https://stackoverflow.com/a/22380248/1794485 allowed me to get this working, or at least as described in his workaround.  But the remaining problem to solve was ordering.

As he said, you can workaround this by having a local copy of the `META-INF/context.xml` somewhere else, and adding this folder to the `Deployment Assembly` in the project properties of the Eclipse project.

This didn't pick up for me initially though.  It looks like that while the `Deployment Assembly` in the properties shows as sorted by name, in fact it has an order like any other path.  When I then removed the `src/main/webapp` entry (so the one containing the normal `META-INF/context.xml`) and added it back in, this effectively moved it down the pecking order.  The next Tomcat deploy and startup in Eclipse finally put my preferred copy of `META-INF/context.xml` in `.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps\myapp\META-INF`

If in doubt about the true sequence of that `Deployment Assembly` path, have a look under your Eclipse project on the file system - at `.settings\org.eclipse.wst.common.component`.

Comment: What do you mean, the `src/main/webapp` entry containing the normal `META-INF/context.xml`? I don't have any `context.xml` checked into my source code at all. In fact I don't even have a `META-INF` in my source tree, or a `web.xml` file. The idea is to put a `context.xml` somewhere _outside_ my source tree, outside version control.

Comment: Ah, cool.  That's actually simpler, as there won't be the two `META-INF/context.xml` to pick between.  With a Maven project, `src/main/webapp` is where you'd put `META-INF/context.xml`, or `WEB-INF/web.xml`, but this doesn't need to apply to you.  If you create such as an `uncontrolled/META-INF/context.xml`, and add `uncontrolled` to `Deployment Assembly` under the project properties, Eclipse should deploy that to `\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps\myapp\META-INF` for you.

Comment: For 200 points, could you maybe provide step-by-step instructions, rather than just referring to Markus' answer and then saying, "that almost worked, but I had to do such and such." What do you mean add the folder to the "Deployment Assembly"? I'm putting up double the normal amount of points here as the bounty. I was hoping somebody would just spell it out for me. Maybe even screenshots. Maybe I'm asking a lot. But I'm giving a lot, too.

Comment: The `Deployment Assembly` is one of the sections in the properties for a project in Eclipse, but I wonder if this isn't showing for you?  If not, probably the best option is to look at the `Project Facets` in the project properties.  You may need to first take the option to `Convert project to faceted form`, then add `Dynamic Web Module` as a facet.  When you OK this, and go back into the project properties this should bring the `Deployment Assembly` section into view.  From there the suggested option to add a folder should be obvious.  
Happy to consolidate the answer if this works out.